# How To Add Perspectives In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

If I have two versions of Eclipse installed, how do I add a perspective that I've installed in one [version of eclipse] to the other?  How do perspectives get added in the first place?  I.e., where do they come from (don't tell me "the 'Open Perspective' dialog")?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the chosen answer is a little bit "poor" on the details on "where do the perspectives come from", here are some precisions:

A **[perspective](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html)** in Eclipse is really just a named organization of views, menus, and toolbars that can be saved and switched to - a unique tab of the application organized for a particular task or set of tasks.

So a perspective comes either from:

- you: you can modify any perspective, adding view, removing menus, adding toolbars, ... and then saving the result (the current modified perspective) under a new name.

[alt text http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_perspective/1.gif](http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_perspective/1.gif)

- a plugin: for that, a plugin **declares a extension point for perspective contribution: org.eclipse.ui.perspectives**.  A new perspective is added to the workbench by defining an extension for this point.  In the example below a perspective extension is defined for the Test Perspective.  This declaration contains the basic elements: id, name and class.

A complete description of the extension point and the syntax are available in the **[developer documentation for org.eclipse.ui](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectives.html)**. The attributes are described as follows.

- **id** - a unique name that will be used to identify this perspective.
- **name** - a translatable name that will be used in the workbench window menu bar to represent this perspective.
- **class** – a fully qualified name of the class that implements org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveFactory interface.
- **icon** - a relative name of the icon that will be associated with this perspective.

This extension point is used to add perspective factories to the workbench.
A perspective factory is used to define the initial layout and visible action sets for a perspective. The user can select a perspective by invoking the "Open Perspective" submenu of the "Window" menu.

---

This is why copying a plugin from one installation of eclipse into the **[dropin folder of the other eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipsehome-plugins/582430#582430)** will make the perspective available to your second Eclipse installation.
(As the last link suggests, you could define a plugin bundle location in order for your two Eclipse to share a common bundle of plugins).

More details on the transfer of plugins between diffent Eclipse (of different versions) in this SO question "[How Do You Reinstall Installed Eclipse Plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627976/how-do-you-reinstall-installed-eclipse-plugins/628041#628041)".

Comment: where can the above drop down menu be accessed? it does not show up on the toolbar for me.

Comment: @ylun.za in five years, the design may have changed. You can see similar buttons with Java or debug at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18635291/6309. This one is seen when right clicking on one of those perspective buttons.

Comment: Yes i have since found it. The settings are now located under the `Window` drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse perspectives are usually defined by features / plugins. If you are missing a certain perspective check the list of installes features / plugins.

Comment: Sure, but what if I have a plugin already installed in one eclipse -- how do I get it to the other?

Comment: you would have to install that plugin in your other instance of eclipse.  The safest way to do this would be via that plugins update site.

Answer (score 0):

Editors and other plug-ins might add their own perspectives. You can also create and save your own perspectives, but I believe you're asking about perspectives added by plug-ins.

The solution is to install the same plug-ins.