# How can I copy an Eclipse installation (Yoxos distribution) to another computer?

Tags: eclipse, copy, installation, yoxos

I'm in the process of switching my whole work environment to a new computer. For PHP developement I use an old Yoxos distribution of Eclipse: and I don't want to build a new one, since I already had difficulties finding my old plugins.

Both computers run Windows 7 64 Bit. So I tried to copy EVERYTHING that has "yoxos" or "eclipse" in it's name/path, including hidden files. But that still does not give me a working Yoxos-Distribution as the launch file is not linked to Yoxos (I guess that would be done in the registry).

**Is there any way to copy Yoxos/Eclipse "as is" to another system?** Do you know of any hazards I might run into while doing this?

*Disclaimer: you probably already noticed that I don't know a hell of a lot about Eclipse :-/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

1) I had to realize what the real problem was: a very old installation of a custom Yoxos package (> 5years) with no Yoxos user account attached to it. At least it seemed that way. I had a new Yoxos account since last year: but that one was not linked to my installation. And vice versa my installation was linked to: nothing. And that was the problem!

2) By trial and error I found out that in my Eclipses Yoxos Perspective I can do the following:
   - log in (Menu "Yoxos") to a user account (new or old doesn't seem to matter).
   - bottom right corner: "Save copy..." There you just give a name and as a folder you use the one that's available there when browsing.

3) Log in to Yoxos, get the Yoxos Launcher and install it on the new computer. That seems to be something like an empty shell for the final Eclipse installation.

4) Start the Launcher on the new computer, log in (Menu "Yoxos"). Now you should be able to see your safed copy (see step 2) in the left tree under "Profiles". Install! That's it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse itself contains all the settings in *INSTALLATION_ROOT/.metadata* directory. These are called "Configuration scope preferences". There are also lower-level scopes - "Instance scope" and "Project Scope" that correspond to workspace and project respectively. So, from bare Eclipse point of view your approach should have worked.

What can happen here is Yoxos or PHP-related metadata are stored somewhere outside configuration scope. I suggest to go through these projects docs (search for registry entries and so on) to see what gets store where.

Other option is downloading a fresh Eclipse instance and then clicking **File -> Import -> Install -> From existing install** referring the old installation copied into the new box. This solution won't preserve your configuration scope preferences though (instance or workspace preferences will be fine).

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346333/exporting-installed-plugins-from-eclipse-to-another) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Pawel! It took my some time to get back to this thing ;-) Your answer helped me get some overview but I ended up playing around with Yoxos in the end - and somehow managed to get it done! I'll add my solution too.