# Reset Eclipse perspective layout

Tags: eclipse, layout, eclipse-juno, perspective, eclipse-kepler

I've just updated from Eclipse Juno to Kepler. What happened to the Eclipse perspective layout and how can I restore it to fill the entire window?

[image: Eclipse Layout]

Comment: Have you tried Window->Reset perspective... ?

Comment: Yes, but it only resets the inner tabs and not the layout size.

Comment: I was debugging my application when it threw an exception... all of a sudden Eclipse layout seems fixed. I... just... don't... want to know what happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the image provided you do indeed have a minimized perspective stack...it's the far right toolbar at the top of the image that has just the icons for the java and debug perspectives. If you click on its 'restore' button the actual perspective will re-appear.

What it looks like is that you have the 'Welcome' (Intro) screen up and maximized (thus the minimized perspective stack). If you were to click the selected item in that top right toolbar the 'fly out' perspective would go away allowing access to the view's restore (un-maximize) button.

Not sure why the Intro's blank though...;-)

Answer (score 15):

Open Windows - Perspective - Other - Select Java (default) and open Windows again and select reset perspective

Answer (score 1):

**You can try press right mouse button in perspective you need reset, after there click in Reset**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows --> Perspective -->Close All Perspective
```

and after that restart Eclipse.