# Saving view layout in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I have a two-screen desktop on which I have arranged eclipse's views in a specific layout. You may call it perspective A.

When I connect to that computer from a laptop, I have to rearrange the views so they could fit into a single smaller scree. You may call it perspective B.

Then when I'm back to the desktop I have to rearrange the views into the perspective A layout.

Question: how can I save these layouts (or "perspectives") so that I could restore the desired layout whenever I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just achieved this in Eclipse (Kepler) by:

Right clicking an existing customised perspective, and clicking 'save as'.

[image]

Then selecting a custom name.

[image]

See the link below for more details.

[How To Add Perspectives In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627914/how-to-add-perspectives-in-eclipse)

Personally I would have separate workspaces configured on each machine that share the same source code. Then use something like [workspace mechanic](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/) to keep the preferences in sync.

Comment: The "save perspective" option does not save the perspective exactly as it is... either an undocumented feature or was is not supposed to support multiple screens.

Comment: The 'perspective' has a 'layout configuration' which is maintained. So are you trying to achieve a global 'layout configuration' for the entire 'workspace' or a 'perspective'?

Comment: I'm not sure where I can control the "layout configuration"? I am trying to achieve a layout that I could accurately restore.. when I create a layout and save it as a perspective A, then switch to another perspective, then switch back to A, A is restored but with several views having the wrong size.. also, when I try to reset the perspective I created, it all gets messed up. If possible, I would like to be able to "set this exact layout as the default of perspective A" so I could do reset perspective, if views are misplaced after switching to a perspective. Or some other perspective solution..