# Rational Team Concert - installing plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I have RTC version 4.0.3 on a Windows 7 system. I would like to install some plugins like PMD, FindBugs, Checkstyle etc. to keep an eye on my code. Are they compatible with RTC?

I've tried installing some and they fail. FindBugs installs successfully, but it's nowhere to be seen in RTC!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a known issue. Having RTC installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)" causes permission issues. I reinstalled into my home folder and plug-in installation works (although not for Findbugs strangely; PMD and Checkstyle are fine).

Answer (score 0):

Check the different [Eclipse perspectives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628005/6309): your plugin could be visible in the Java perspective, while being not available in the RTC one.

Comment: Yep I've looked in the Java perspective and no luck!

Comment: @user2119522 What version of Eclipse is your RTC 4.0.3 using? 3.6?

Comment: Yes, it's using Eclipse platform version 3.6.3