# Setting up PyDev in Eclipse Juno

Tags: pydev

I have installed Eclipse Juno on a linux machine and am trying to set up PyDev.
I have installed PyDev using Help => Install New Software, and it seemed to work fine and is listed as installed:
[image: PyDev installed]

However, I do not find PyDev under Preferences, and I don't find the PyDev Perspective.
[image: PyDev missing]

Any suggestions on how to get this running? (I'm normally a Windows user...)

Comment: You could be in a custom perspective in which the plugin commands are not set to be visible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627914/how-to-add-perspectives-in-eclipse

another way:
sudo eclipse -clean; 
Help -->  Install software --> Re-install the plugins and software;
Explanation:
Eclipse is installed and the majority of programs are also installed initially with root privileges.

Typically 'Ownership' of hidden install folders like this belong to the 'Sudo' or Root user. Therefore changes and installs to these hidden folders will not take.

Answer (score 0):

You could be in a custom perspective in which the plugin commands are not set to be visible [How To Add Perspectives In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627914/how-to-add-perspectives-in-eclipse)

**Another way:**

```
sudo eclipse -clean; 
Help -->  Install software --> Re-install the plugins and software;
```

Explanation:
Eclipse is installed and the majority of programs are also installed initially with root privileges.

Typically 'Ownership' of hidden install folders like this belong to the 'sudo' or Root user. Therefore changes and installs to these hidden folders will not take.

Answer (score 0):

Your requisites aren't Ok. PyDev 5.6 requires Neon (Eclipse 4.6).

See: **Need to use older Eclipse/Java/Python** in http://www.pydev.org/download.html for details on the PyDev version you need for older versions of Eclipse (also, make sure your java version matches the requisite).