# Can an extra plugin directory be specified on command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

With Eclipse 3.4, is it possible to provide an ADDITIONAL plugin directory from command line? Something like:

```
eclipse -plugin_dir  D:/myproduct/V1.1/plugins -clean
```

This is just to save copying of plugins everytime.

While copying can be done with script,  it's possible that user may not have 
write permissions to system install eclipse.

---

#### Follow up:

The solution given by @VonC is for reusing same plugins in multiple Eclipses.

I'm looking for a to use Multiple versions of plugins with Same Eclipse.
  ( If user has Version 1.1 and Vesion 1.2 of my plugin installed )

#### Resolved:

1. The directory pointed to by -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory
   should end with a directory named   'eclipse'
2. Inside this eclipse where should be directory called plugins,
3. place all the jars at in the plugins directory
4. create a launcher , which launch eclipse with additional command line:

> -vmargs
>   -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=AbsolutePath\eclipse

One may want to add `-clean` also ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in [Installing Eclipse (3.4+) plugins in a directory other than ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipsehome-plugins), the right way is to define a **[bundle pools](http://ekkes-corner.blogspot.com/2008/06/eclipse-ganymede-p2-shared.html)** (also [introduced here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Bundle_pooling))

[image]

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipsehome-plugins/582430#582430) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It space is not a big issue, users can copy the system install of eclipse into a work directory and put additional plugins/features in the `dropins/` directory.