# Installing a local Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse(3.4.2) installed in a central area(read-only), on a Linux machine. There are a lot of pre-installed plug-ins. But I want to add some of mine. I have a .jar file for the plug-in but I don't know where to place/extract it.

Comment: go to help>install new software, add local site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two threads that contain information that should help - 1) [Installing Eclipse (3.4+) plugins in a directory other than ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipse-home-plugins), 2) [Can an extra plugin directory be specified on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680642/can-an-extra-plugin-directory-be-specified-on-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single jar file you will need to add it to the "/dropins" folder that is in the central area.  You can not use the "add local site" option unless you have the entire updatesite

Comment: Yeah I was fuzzy as well when p2/dropins first showed up. But I downloaded a 3.4.2 SDK zip and saw that it had dropins folder, which makes sense because p2 was introduced in Eclipse 3.4.