# what clearcase plugin to use with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clearcase

Which Clearcase plugin should I use for eclipse 3.5+?

- which is easiest to use?
- which is most reliable?
- can any of the plugins handle working with multiple views cleanly?

Comment: cue a dozen responses about not using clearcase ;)

Comment: Did you manage to install successfully the IBM ClearCase eclipse plugin?

Comment: I found this [comparison table](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/eclipse-ccase/index.php?title=Feature_comparison_to_the_IBM_ClearCase_plugin) on the open-source plugin's wiki to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the open plugin to work perfectly:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/
installed through the automatic updates and worked out of the box :)

Answer (score 7):

I found a clearcase adapter update site for windows on ibm at: http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/

The link at IBM Download is broken.

Comment: does this plugin still require you to download and install it manually instead of through the eclipse plugin manager?

Comment: This plugin does no longer work with the new Eclipse Luna. Anybody knows an IBM link to a plugin that works with Luna?

Comment: The Clearcase plugin for Eclipse (http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/) at Sourceforge seems to work with Luna.

Answer (score 5):

You can install [CC plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/2500/2834/ClearCase/clearcase%5Fplugins.html) 3.4 without any problem in a [shared bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipsehome-plugins/582430#582430) repository.
Unzip them in order to have, in your own directory outside eclipse (unzip each files into their respective directories):

```
myPlugins
  com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh.all_os-20081031A
    eclipse
      features
        com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh_7.0.0.20081031A
     plugins
        com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh_7.0.0.20081031A
  com.rational.clearcase.win32-20081031A
    eclipse
      features
        com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccimport.feature_7.0.0.20070612B
        com.rational.clearcase_7.0.0.20081031A
      plugins
        com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccimport_7.0.0.20070612B
        com.rational.clearcase.activities_7.0.0.20081031A
        com.rational.clearcase.help_7.0.0.20081031A
        com.rational.clearcase_7.0.0.20081031A
```

It will be picked up by the new [provisioning mechanism p2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/P2) with eclipse3.5, provided you mention the right option in your eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory= /your_path/e34shared_dropin
```

That way, you can reference them from any eclipse3.4 or eclipse3.5 installation you might have (just a line to add in your [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349)).

---

[Cid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966078/cid) reference in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1175738#comment16321983_1175738) the following notes from "[Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.0.0.2](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024213)":

> **When installing into Eclipse 3.5.x you may need to uncheck "**Group items by category**" to see the entries for installation**.
>   For SCM Adapter there is no need to check anything other than "`Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter`" as the other entry (Rational ClearCase Remote Client for Eclipse Import) is a subfeature of the SCM Adapter and will automaticaly be included.

Comment: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024213 Uncheck the "Group items by category" to see the entries for installation.

Comment: @Cid: good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Good luck downloading the [plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/2500/2834/ClearCase/clearcase%5Fplugins.html) it is 404.
You can add an update site

```
 Window>Preferences>Install/Update>Add...

 http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows
```

There are problems with the plugin in 3.5.  None of the menu or configurations work.  However, it will handle multiple views, it will checkout.

Answer (score 0):

If you must, ClearCase comes with an SCM Adapter when it is installed.  Try using that.

Comment: When you run the ClearCase installer on your computer, during the installation process you can select "Clearcase SCM Adapter" for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Worked well using HELIOS, but would not install under INDIGO.

> Error "cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is
>   not applicable".

Testing out the OpenSource alternative as suggested above. They work a little bit different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The current page for IBM's adapter is here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674

It includes the following section:

> **Alternative installation Mechanism:**
>
> It is also possible to install the plugin using the eclipse update
>   mechanism. The eclipse update URLs needed are as follows:  SCM Adapter
>   for Eclipse on Windows
>   http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/
>
> SCM Adapter for Eclipse on Solaris/Linux
>   http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/unix/

For a CLI install from a Linux system, try:

```
/path/to/eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-repository http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/unix/ \
-installIU com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh.feature.group,com.rational.clearcase.linux.feature.group
```

Answer (score 0):

The ClearTeam Explorer (CTE) can be added to installed Eclipse instances and provides a deep integration with ClearCase.  See the ClearCase V8.0.1 Knowledge Center topic:

[Installation of the Rational ClearTeam Explorer for Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_inst_ccrc_eclipse.htm)

CTE was introduced in ClearCase V8.0 at which time it supported dynamic views and Web views.  ClearCase V8.0.1.6 added snapshot view support.  CTE immediately supported automatic views when they were introduced in ClearCase V8.0.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this pluging:
Can be installed automatically from Eclipse

Help -> Install New SW -> Add

http://eclipse-ccase.sourceforge.net/update/

Answer (score -2):

You can [download the files](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/2500/2834/ClearCase/clearcase_plugins.html) you need from IBM. If you have Eclipse 3.5, you can use the Eclipse 3.4 plugin (as I do at work).

EDIT: Apparently, the page is down. It is the page linked to on [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/08/cc_plugin_eclipse3.4/) to obtain the Eclipse plugins.

Comment: installing the rational clear case plugin was painful on eclipse 3.3 when last i tried it. has it improved?

Comment: I had no problem. I downloaded the ZIP, added a new local update site, and was good to go.