# What Clearcase eclipse-plugin to use in order to work on both clearcase 6 and 7 projects?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase

Using Eclipse 3.5, what clearcase plugin to use in order for me to work on both clearcase 6 and 7 projects?

Comment: Note: if you have specific error messages when accessing CC6 views, please edit your question, for me or other SO users to examine.

Comment: Just added a precision and a question in my answer, could you check it out?

Answer (score 2):

I confirm the latest version of the IBM [ClearCase Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse) presented here on the [IBM site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/08/cc_plugin_eclipse3.4/)

- does work with eclipse3.5 even though it is for eclipse3.4
- support [CC6 and CC7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21256383)

You just need to be careful about:

- your [`\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SourceCodeControlProvider\` value](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=2042&context=SSRTLW&dc=DB520&uid=swg21130782&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8%25E2%258C%25A9=en&rss=ct2042rational)
- your [Extension Location link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21380025).

Note: the [official IBM download page for this plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/2500/2834/ClearCase/clearcase_plugins.html) seems unavailable at the moment.

That means you must use the update p2 mechanism to access the:

- CC eclipse plugin [update site for Windows](http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/)

or

- CC eclipse plugin [update site for Unix](http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/unix/)

Note:

Can you access those CC6 views with a classical ClearCase client?
Because it may very well turn out that you cannot (and, by extension, that would explain the eclipse CC plugin cannot either)

A view is attached to a view server through its view storage.
If that view storage is stored locally on his/her desktop, that make that desktop a CC6.0 view server.
If your CC7.0 view storages are stored on your desktop, that make your desktop a CC7.0 view server.

And a CC7.0 view server cannot access a CC6.0 view server.

Comment: Hi VonC, so the eclipse plugin should work on both versions 6 and 7? Need to retry this one since it didn't work for me. What are differences between the eclipse plugin(SCM adapter??) and the CCRC eclipse plugin?

Comment: Ooops. I should ask another question.

Comment: Yes VonC, I couldn't access using the classic ClearCase client with other version. Even the Eclipse CCRC plugin works the same way too. Now, I'm hoping that the SCM adapter will work on both projects. 
Haven't tried it yet since I have mixed up my devt env now. Have both SCM adapter and CCRC eclipse plugin installed in single Eclipse installation. I should try installing the SCM adapter and see if things workout.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/ccrc/701/update/