# How would you integrate ClearCase in our Android App development?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin, clearcase, configuration-management

My friend and I are working simultaneously on Android App Development on Eclipse IDE 3.6 - Win 7 Operating System.

What would be the best ClearCase Tool and please provide details steps to install and integrate to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- install the IBM ClearCase plugin (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1175738#1175738), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297176/what-clearcase-eclipse-plugin-to-use-in-order-to-work-on-both-clearcase-6-and-7-p/1297739#1297739)): the GUI -- Eclipse with ClearCase -- [will look like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857):

[image: ClearCase with Eclipse GUI]

- work both in your respective snapshot view (that way you can work on the same branch, but only merge the updates of your colleague when you are updating your snapshot view).