# eclipse - building projects dependent on jars - created during ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, clearcase

I am experiencing a problem with Eclipse's building its projects.

The procedure for setting a dev env is:

1. Creating a clearcase view.
2. Opening eclipse.
3. Importing preferences.
4. Connecting to clearcase plugin.
5. Importing a team-set.
6. Running ant - `build.xml`

During the `build.xml`, some files are generated and moved from its working directory into the some projects' lib directories.

After that, there are some `eclipse.referesh` task and `eclipse.incrementalBuild` that the `build.xml` invokes.

Now, the projects the jars (generated during `build.xml`) were copied into, do get compiled successfully, but other projects depending on them do not.

Even if I try refreshing the entire workspace and clean-building all of its projects manually, this doesn't work.

The problem is resolved only when I close the projects and open them (an eclipse feature).

It is possible that this is happening due to the ClearCase plugin?
Anyway on how to resolve this problem (It causes the `build.xml` to fail, because of compiler problems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the official [IBM ClearCase Eclipse plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/07/cc_eclipse3_2/clearcase_plugins.html) (presented in "[What Clearcase eclipse-plugin to use in order to work on both clearcase 6 and 7 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297176/what-clearcase-eclipse-plugin-to-use-in-order-to-work-on-both-clearcase-6-and-7/1297739#1297739)"), I don't have that kind of issue if:

**the .project and .classpath are within the ClearCase view, alongside the versioned sources**
(see "[Clearcase plugin for eclipse usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857)")

In other words, all files (eclipse files, ant files, ...) should be parth of the project directory, *outside* of the eclipse workspace itself (said eclipse workspace contains only a reference to the project, none of the actual files part of a ClearCase views, and located elsewhere, where the CC view actually is)

If you respect that organization, then the ClearCase plugin should have 0 effect on what your project are doing.

Comment: Thank you. The *.classpath and *.project are indeed part of the view.

Comment: @user967710 then the CC plugin itself shouldn't prevent any part of the projects to build.

Comment: So problem really isn't the CC plugin. So what can it be?

Comment: @user967710 are all the generated files done within the CC views, or generated in the Eclipse workspace. Try to keep the two well separated.