# Easy way of installing Eclipse plugins on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, installation, versions

I'm running Eclipse (versions 3.6 and 3.5) on Ubuntu and I'm having trouble installing Eclipse plugins.

There is an [easy way to install eclipse plugins in Eclipse](http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/), but this doesn't work for me on Ubuntu! This way only works properly under Windows and Mac OSX.

Just like in the tutorial, I create a folder inside my eclipse SDK folder that is named *Links*.
In this folder, I create a file `eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.lnk` or `eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.link` that contains this line:

```
path=/home/taher/opt/eclipse/Third-party-eclipse-links/eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk
```

and save it, but when I start Eclipse doesn't recognize the plugin!

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Eclipse Galileo (3.5) or Helios (3.6), I would rather recommend an external directory called 'mydropins' (for instance), which you can reference from your **[`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659)**, with the option:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/Prog/Java/eclipse_addons
```

This is called a **[shared dropins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891)**.
See in this [SO answer an example of plugin deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1175738#1175738) in this shared dropins folder.

---

(Your link refers to the previous provisioning mechanism, pre-p2.
[P2 is the new provisioning system](http://wiki.eclipse.org/P2) introduced late in Eclipse3.4, refined (debugged?) in eclipse 3.5 and 3.6.
See the [supported dropins formats](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins) to check how you can organize your own personal dropins folder (that you can reuse between several eclipse installations)

---

You said you are using:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/home/taher/opt/eclipse/Third-party-eclipse-links
```

That means, under /home/taher/opt/eclipse/Third-party-eclipse-links, you:

- won't have any `.link` file
- will copy:

```
    eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk
      eclipse
        features
        plugins
```

Note: the structure within `eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk` should be the one describe above, for p2 to pick it up.

Comment: please help me do this in linux my eclipse.ini content is
[code]
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
[/code]

Comment: I paste my plugins jee and CDT to dropins folder but they doesn't work properly in  eclipse SDK and eclipse SDK doesn't recognize them!!!

Comment: @taher: just follow the link I gave you on eclipse.ini: you will have one optimized, simplified (no need for `startup` or `launcher.library` options), and with the right `p2.reconciler.dropins.directory` in it.

Comment: @taher: then, leave in a comment the exact structure of files you have for the cpp plugins.