# Upgrading from Eclipse Galileo to Helios

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-3.5

Whats the best way to upgrade from Galileo to Helios whilst still preserving my settings and plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The surest path to upgrade is to make a "parallel" installation: an Helios Eclipse beside the Galileo one you already have.

Regarding your settings, you just need to reference the same workspace.
In your [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659), indicate where your workspace is, and you will get back all your projects, workspaces and perspectives just as you left them.

Plugins are trickier, and I would recommend:

- adding to your eclipse.ini a [shared dropins directory reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324639/easy-way-installing-eclipse-plugins/3324690#3324690)
- copying the extra plugins from your Galileo installation to that shared dropins one.
  See [How to copy plugins between two eclipses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854765/how-to-copy-plugins-between-two-eclipses/2854782#2854782)

In your shared dropins path, you will have:

```
   my-eclipse-galileo-plugins
     eclipse
       features
       plugins
```

and you will copy all extra plugins and features added since the installation of your Eclipse Galileo instance:

```
   /path/to/galileo
     eclipse
       features
       plugins
```

Answer (score 3):

Note, to upgrade from Galileo to Helios (3.6), you first need to add the Helios software repository as follows:

1. Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites
2. Click 'Add'
3. Enter URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
4. Click 'Ok'

From [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F#Eclipse_Galileo_.283.5.29_and_beyond)

Answer (score 1):

The method above did not work for me on one of my 3 boxes.  I had the usual dependency issue that Eclipse gets so wrong so often.

What worked for me on my second Ubuntu box was Method 2 found in this article:
http://crlog.info/2011/06/30/upgrading-eclipse-on-ubuntu-from-3-5-to-3-7-indigo-works-for-other-versions-too/

Method 1 from the article worked on my Windows and one of my Ubuntu boxes, but Method 2 was required for the other Ubuntu box.