# Download Glassfish Adapter plugin separately

Tags: eclipse, plugins, glassfish

Is it possible to download Glass-fish adapter plug-in for eclipse(Helios) separately not with 'Install New Software feature in eclipse'?

Because I want to archive this plug-in and use it on another eclipse instances.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer:

- install it through "Install new feature" (see [How to install the GlassFish 3 server adapter with Eclipse Helios 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538433/how-to-install-the-glassfish-3-server-adapter-with-eclipse-helios-3-6))
- and then move all its plugin and features `.jar` files into a [shared dropins directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408961/upgrading-from-eclipse-galileo-to-helios/3409052#3409052).

```
    /path/to/mydropins/
       glassfish
         eclipse
            plugins
              <= move the glassfish plugins.jar files here 
            features
              <= move the glassfish features.jar files here
```

([see `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) to reference a shared dropins)

That way, any Eclipse installation which

Comment: But what should I do if I want to move only Glass-fish plug-ins and features not all ??? How do i find for example Glass-fish jars in those hundred jars?

Comment: @Navid: I usually make a list (dir or ls) of files before installation, and then one list after installation. I move the diff.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse](http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/) from the home page of the [GlassFish Plug-ins](https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/).