# Eclipse plugin for Notepad++

Tags: eclipse-plugin, notepad++

I have tried associating Notepad++ as the default editor for some of my file types inside eclipse. However, they open in an external window. I would like them to open inside my IDE.

Is there any Eclipse plugin for integrating Notepad++ inside Eclipse as an internal editor?

Comment: Notepad++ itself uses [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org) as its editing component. Are you looking to integrate the entire Notepad++ interface or just its editing component into Eclipse?

Comment: @BoltClock: I am trying to use Notepad ++ as an internal editor instead of an external program in order to edit text / source files inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest existing project is [Jintilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jintilla/), which provides an integration path for Eclipse to use [Scintilla](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Notepad%2B%2B_And_Scintilla). Install it by placing the JAR file in the plugins directory, then restart Eclipse.

Comment: How can i do this in 64 bit ubuntu os ..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Search for [Eclipse folder plugin Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324639/easy-way-of-installing-eclipse-plugins-on-ubuntu/3324690#3324690) for platform specific details.