# Is it possible to use notepad++ as inline text editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, notepad++

I am just wondering if its possible to open notepad++ as inline text editor in eclipse. So I can enjoy both features of elipse and notepad++ together. I am targeting html and js files.

Comment: What are the features you enjoy from notepad++? Maybe you can get them in Eclipse.

Comment: Probably this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603615/eclipse-plugin-for-notepad will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse IDE is made with Java and Notepad++ is made with Delphi. I don't think they are compatible, unless a new version of Notepad++ had ActiveX capabilities.

I wish Eclipse had the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse</kbd> ability to point many places in the screen and type them at the same time. Other great feature is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+MouseSelection that allows us to make squared selection, copy, paste and type at them...

Comment: Both Eclipse and Notepad++ have block selection, copy, and paste. Toggle in Eclipse with `alt+shift+A`. In Notepad++ hold `alt`.