# Eclipse CDT Linux ClearCase SCM Adapter plug-in install problems

Tags: linux, version-control, clearcase, eclipse-cdt, adapter

I'm having a silly little problem with Eclipse. I'm trying to install Rational ClearCase SCM adapter in Eclipse (Helios SR1) CDT Linux 64 bit.
I downloaded ClearCase plug-in form [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/07/cc_eclipse3_2/clearcase_plugins.html). I tried both SCM adapter version 7.0.0.2 and 7.5.0.0. I got this error in both case?

> Cannot complete the install because
>   some dependencies are not satisfiable 
>   com.rational.clearcase.linux.feature.group
>   [7.0.0.20081031A] cannot be installed
>   in this environment because its filter
>   is not applicable.

My clearcase version is not exactly the same as the adapter. Is this why? In this case, where can I dowload SCM adapter for v 7.1 ?

```
linuxcc7$ ct -version
ClearCase version 7.1.0.00 (Tue Nov 11 00:18:47 EST 2008) (7.1.D081110)
@(#) MVFS version 7.1.0.0 (Mon Oct 13 20:06:10 2008) built at $Date: 2010-11-12.14:19:20 (UTC) $
cleartool         7.1.0.0 (Sat Oct 25 22:52:22 2008) 
db_server         7.1.0.0 (Sat Oct 25 22:53:08 2008)
```

I have no idea what filter is it complaining about. Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older version of Eclipse, also on Linux 32 still have problems with IBM Rational Clearcase plugin 7.x.

Finally I end up using [open source plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/), install straight forward and works very well.

Note: After installing the open source plugin, make sure you restart the eclipse. Also after creating a new project or project from existing source, make sure you associate the project with ClearCase. (Choose Team-->Associate With ClearCase in Project context menu)

Answer (score 3):

IBM support says that SCM Adapter is **not** officially supported on 64 bit operating system. Check [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460547) for a *workaround* on non-Windows installation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the [Eclipse CDT package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) is the most suited one for ClearCase plugin.

I tried a classic RCP Eclipse package, both with the [update site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1246932#1246932), or externally with a [shared dropins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1175738#1175738), each time successfully.