# Custom Eclipse package

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to package Eclipse + a few custom plugins, for internal use.

The package will contain the

- Platform Runtime Binary ( win32 and linux x86 gtk );
- Mylyn Task List;
- Mylyn Focused UI;
- Mantis Connector for Mylyn.

How can I produce these custom builds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the article "**[Composing and updating custom Eclipse distros](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/07/composing-and-updating-custom-eclipse.html)**" for eclipse Galileo.

If that approach is too complex, you can simply define a [shared plugin directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipsehome-plugins) in which you will dump the common plugins you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would try taking a ready zip from the Eclipse site and putting these three plugins into the `plugins` and `features` directory.

Comment: Since you are formulating this as a question, I'm not sure if you are suggesting this as something worth trying or as something that you know to work without problems. Could you clarify/edit, please?