# How can I download an Eclipse plugin as a zip archive using an update site?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, offline

I have Eclipse installed on a box which is off the Internet.

I found this package I want to install, but I only have an update URL for it, not an archive file I can copy to the disconnected machine and put in its Eclipse' `dropins/` folder  like with some other extensions.

On a machine connected to the Internet, how do I obtain/create an archive file, having only access to the update URL?

**Notes:**

- I tried making a local mirror of the update site, as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257271/tool-for-downloading-eclipse-plugins-from-update-sites), but that didn't really work out for me. The mirror still referred to the remote repository and Eclipse tried to go there.
- Please make no assumptions regarding the operating systems and configurations of any of the machines (and don't assume the two machines are the same).

Comment: If the machine is the same OS and architecture you could just copy your Eclipse folder onto a flash drive, execute Eclipse there, update / install, and copy the folder back to the original machine.

Comment: It's not the same OS and architecture, and the machine connected to the Internet does not even have Eclipse installed...

Comment: There would be no need to install Eclipse, you can run it from the folder, it is self-contained. But of course you would need permission to execute the application. In fact as most plugins are just Java you could even copy the `plugins`/`features` folders from a different system (not in all cases, e.g. Android will not work this way).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool for downloading eclipse plugins from update sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257271/tool-for-downloading-eclipse-plugins-from-update-sites)

Comment: @Bananeweizen: That post was satisfied by mirroring an update site to a local update site, but I want to have an archive, not a local mirror, so it isn't a dupe. A local update site would be a second best. **however** the solutions suggested there don't work for me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading Eclipse plug-in update sites for offline installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation)

Comment: @oberlies: It's not a duplicate, since I don't want an update site, just a package I can drop-into Eclipse. Unfortunately it seems the solution suggested involves created an update site.

Comment: "The mirror still referred to the remote repository" - This must be related to the infamous mirrors.xml stuff in p2 repositories. The solution to this problem is usually to be offline - in this case p2 will actually use the local copy. Plus, the local mirror contains the plug-ins from the remote repository, so you could try to just drop in that plugin into the installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using `wget` instead of mirroring.

Here are the brief steps, with some update site chosen for the example:

1. Download the update site to your local machine:

   ```
   wget --recursive --no-parent http://run-jetty-run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite
   ```
2. Take the content of the downloaded update site and move it to your offline environment, preserving the directory structure.
3. Open Eclipse and add your offline update site directory to the list of available software sites via “Local…” button.

You can see those steps in details [here](http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/how-to-download-eclipse-update-site-for-offline-use/).

Comment: Would you mind summarizing your note (in a couple of lines) here, for an upvote?

Comment: @einpoklum Sure, will do.

Comment: Now I just need to try it.

Comment: @einpoklum Did you validate that? I'll be glad to hear your comments.

Comment: Sorry, not yet... once I worked around that problem it hasn't come up for a while, and I'm too busy with a bunch of other things. I guess I'll take you at your word and accept :-)\

Answer (score 1):

[Nirmal had it covered!](http://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/provisioning-your-target-platform-as-local-p2-site/)

1. Create a Target Platform with the required feature from the update site you need.
2. Create your own update site definition with PDE.
3. Build your own update site.

Now you have a part of remote update site archived. You can use it on offline machine by pointing installer to look for update site in a local folder.

...

PROFIT!