# How to change Eclipse-Groovy plugin Groovy libraries?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, buildpath, eclipse-classpath

I am using the newest version (2.8.0) of the [Eclipse-Groovy](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse) plugin that ships with `groovy-all-2.1.5.jar`. I added Guice to my Groovy project, and when I go to run them from inside Eclipse I get the following error in the console output:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
    at net.me.myapp.utils.restclient.RestClient.<init>(RestClient.groovy:57)
    at net.me.myapp.inject.UserServiceClientModule.configure(UserServiceClientModule.groovy:34)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at net.me.myapp.UserServiceClient.<init>(UserServiceClient.groovy:37)
    at net.me.myapp.UserServiceClient.main(UserServiceClient.groovy:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling
    ... 12 more
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23860786/4009451) it's because `ShortTypeHandling` wasn't added until 2.3.x. So I would now like to attach `groovy-all-2.3.3.jar` to my Eclipse project's classpath.

The problem is that I don't seem to have edit permissions to change what library the `Groovy Libraries` library uses under the hood. And when I manually add the 2.3.3 JAR to my build path, I get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.1.5 and you are trying to load version 2.3.3
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groovy-eclipse versions have its own compilers [and are "locked" to them](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Switching+within+Groovy-Eclipse). You may change the versions to whatever is listed under Window > Preferences > Groovy > Compilers, but, AFAIK, you can't change to an arbitrary version of the compiler by simply changing the `groovy-all` jar in the guts of the plugin dir.

[image: groovy-eclipse compiler version change]

You can install new compiler versions using the [update site](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) or eclipse marketplace

---

**Update:** install additional compiler versions through Help > Install new Software, select Groovy update site and expand the `Extra Groovy Compilers` session:

[image]

Note i'm using snapshot update site, because i [like to live dangerously](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8f/d5/5e/8fd55ed8bf10e555d22181cb1724f629.jpg).

Comment: Thanks @Will P (+1) - I think you might have found the solution here, however in my eclipse, I don't se a "*Switch to 2.3.3.xx...*" button/option. I only have buttons for 1.8.7 and 2.0.7, which doesn't help me out because `ShortTypeHandling` wasn't introduced until 2.3.x. **Do you know how I could add more versions to my *Groovy Compiler Settings* options?** Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb I have the same issue. I installed the 2.4 feature but there's no button to switch to it in my preferences. Did you ever resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I found an answer that works for me: add -clean to the eclipse.ini file. Thanks to @Lari Hotari (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413003/groovy-compiler-mismatch-after-installation).