# Eclipse-Groovy plugin: Adding new Groovy compiler versions

Tags: eclipse, groovy, configuration, eclipse-plugin

I installed the [Groovy-Eclipse plugin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) for my Eclipse (Kepler) IDE.

When I go to `Windows >> Preferences >> Groovy >> Compiler`, I see:

[image]

Notice the two "*Switch to...*" buttons that currently give me the option of switching the Groovy compiler to the **1.8.6** or **2.0.7** version.

My question: **how do I add a new "*Switch to...*" button for the the 2.3.3 Groovy compiler?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was answered in an edit to your other question's answer [How to change Eclipse-Groovy plugin Groovy libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046380/how-to-change-eclipse-groovy-plugin-groovy-libraries/26047249#26047249)

For your version of eclipse you can add this update site if you don't already have it http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/

Then install the `Groovy Compiler 2.3 Feature`