# Uninstalling plugins/features does not remove files under eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse 3.5. I understand that eclipse platform is defined by the plugins present under the eco system. However, I see that the plugin details are duplicated under workspace '`C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins`' and installation directory '`C:\eclipse\plugins`'.

If I uninstall plugins (using `Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation details`), I find that the actual files are not removed.
Can I manually change the `.metadata` directory contents and be happy or am I missing some thing?
How do I ensure that the `.metadata\plugins` are also removed when I uninstall plugins/features? Where does eclipse pick the configuration details from?

I have multiple workspaces and workspace is not my default workspace.
I have actually ran uninstall on one of the workspaces, as one of the plugins was significantly effecting the platform. The metadata entries and plugin directory contents are still there, but the problem is resolved.
Which still raises the question, can I delete the files manually? I have only one eclipse installation (not a shared one, hence no version conflicts)

Answer (score 0):

I have never fiddled with `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins`, as it contains properties for the installed plugins that you might need should you re-install a plugin you previously removed.

I always move all installed plugins in a [shared dropins directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipse-home-plugins/582430#582430), which allows me:

- to share a set of plugins amongst several workspace/eclipse installations
- to remove a plugin manually to deleting it directly within that shared directory.