# How to install plugins to external folder for re-use with new version of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a set of plugins that I always need in eclipse. I also like to keep up to date with the latest version of eclipse.

So what this means is every time I update eclipse I have to re-install all the plugins I need.

How do I install these plugins to an external folder so that they can be picked up by the new installation of eclipse?

Comment: I think this answer is what you're looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipse-home-plugins

Comment: thanks for that, I'm hoping for simpler instructions

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Instead use *File -> Export -> Install -> Software Items to file* on your old installation to create a file listing your current plugins. In the second installation import the file accordingly. Make sure to check the checkbox to search for newer versions during the import.

This requires Eclipse 3.7+.