# Eclipse RCP: move all plugins to .eclipseextension

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have 2+ RCP applications in the 32/64 variants on Eclipse 4.3 (windows). When i do export them, i get all the platform plugins 4+ times.

What I have now:

```
\application1
     \win32.win32.x86
          \plugins (60MB)
     \win32.win32.x86_x64
          plugins (60MB)
\application2
     \win32.win32.x86
          \plugins (60MB)
     \win32.win32.x86_x64
          \plugins (60MB)
```

Now these application are distributed over network, so the size does matter.
Is there a way, i can have the 95% of plugins, which are the same in these directories, in one shared folder with relative path?

What i want to have:

```
\platform
     \plugins (60MB)
\application1
     \win32.win32.x86
          \plugins (<5MB) + link to "../../platform"
     \win32.win32.x86_x64
          \plugins (<5MB) + link to "../../platform"
\application2
     \win32.win32.x86
          \plugins (<5MB) + link to "../../platform"
     \win32.win32.x86_x64
          \plugins (<5MB) + link to "../../platform"
```

In this scenario, the platform holds the common stuff. In the separated folders, there is only the minimal startup plugins and my application plugins.

Is this somehow doable?
To go to that structure should be to an automated process,
so manual GUI interactions are not good.

thx 
Frank

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Eclipse (3.4+) plugins in a directory other than ECLIPSE\_HOME/plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipse-home-plugins)

Comment: Also see http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/12/16/the-easy-way-to-reinstall-eclipse-and-share-plugins-across-multiple-installations/
and http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html. The keyword you want to google for is "eclipse bundlepool"

Comment: This question is a lot better than the supposed duplicate, so I wouldn't close it.

Comment: user2572894, although the question is good, it will not be accepted on stackoverflow in its current form. The reason is that you are asking us to find a tool which does what you want, and to this question there are no neutral answers. You could fix this question if you describe what build tool you are using - and ask how to achieve your goal with that build tool.

Comment: I use the PDE export wizard to get my current file layout. From my researches and the links provided by you and Fredrik, i can see, i need to use the p2.director.
It is very hard for me to find the way to my wanted solution. Many information points to the no more existing p2.installer, and those information is old like 2008, and people in newer comments say it is no more working.
Or it shows how to install plugins into a bundlepool for an existing eclipse.

Comment: I was searching for the needed steps, current http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/746045/ is my current state. Any hints are **very** welcome